# Exception with generic set of ConstraintViolations

Tags: java, generics

I am working on some service code that is using JSR-303 validation to test a request object.  What I would like to do is throw a custom RuntimeException when the validation fails containing the `Set` of `ConstraintViolations`.

All of my request objects ultimately implement the same interface, lets call it `Request`.  I think have an `AbstractRequest` that implements `Request`, and then a bunch of implementations of `AbstractRequest`, for instance `MyRequest`.

For the exception, what I am trying to do is something like:

```
public class RequestViolationException extends RuntimeException {
  private Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends Request>> violations;

  public <T extends Request> RequestViolationException(Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> newViolations) {
    this.violations = newViolations;
  }
}
```

And I am calling it like:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<MyRequest>> violations = validator.validate(myRequest);
if (violations.size() > 0) {
  throw new RequestViolationException(violations);
}
```

But this is not working.  I have tried a few other variations on this theme, like making the constructor take a `Set<ConstraintViolation<? extends Request>>`, making `violations` a `Set<ContraintViolation<Message>>`, making `violations` a `Set<ContraintViolation<Message>>`, setting it to a `HashSet<ContraintViolation<Message>>` then iterating of `newViolations`, etc.  Each has proven to give a myriad of different compiler errors.  How can I have a `Set` of `ContraintViolation<T>` where `<T>` is some extension of `Request` and have it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend an exception with generics:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCatch

Comment: I know you can't extend a generic with exceptions, but what I want is the generic on the set, not the exception.  I guess what I am asking is if there is a way to have a set of superclass/interface where I can pass in a set of set/superclasses easily.

Answer (score 1):

Actually @JGilardi is right, your constructor accepts `<T extends Request>` but you are trying to assign it to instance variable `violations` which is `<? extends Request>` which is illegal. Please refer to 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html for a detailed explanation.

To parameterize the instance variable with the same `<T extends Request>` you have to parameterize the class which again extends `RuntimeException` and thus not parameterizable. :(